# Simplify binding for non-standard button

Tags: wpf, binding, wpf-controls, caliburn.micro

We are using [Caliburn Micro](http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/documentation) and it's pretty nice but now we are using the new [Ribbon](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff799534.aspx) control (which comes with .NET 4.5). This control has [RibbonButton](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windows.controls.ribbon.ribbonbutton.aspx) and while this button has a click event and it's, well, a button, it seems Caliburn doesn't auto fire the action when it's name match the viewmodel method one.

Now, we can fix this by using `cal:Message.Attach="ViewHelp"` but given the pretty big amount of controls within the ribbon bar I was wondering if there's an easy way to make the auto binding  to work between the `RibbonButton` and the `ViewModel` method.

Comment: Interesting because the default "click" convention is registered for `ButtonBase` with the following statement `AddElementConvention<ButtonBase>(ButtonBase.ContentProperty, "DataContext", "Click");` as described in [this article](http://devlicio.us/blogs/rob_eisenberg/archive/2010/12/16/caliburn-micro-soup-to-nuts-part-7-all-about-conventions.aspx). And based on MSDN the `RibbonButton` is inherited from `ButtonBase` so I would expect it to work...

Comment: @nemesv Sure, that's precisely what's weird.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use ConventionManager. Start from this:

```
ConventionManager.AddElementConvention<RibbonButton>(
    RibbonButton.ContentProperty, "DataContext", "Click");
```

Place this code inside your Bootstrapper. Like this:

```
public class AppBootstrapper : Bootstrapper
{
    protected override void Configure()
    {
        ConventionManager.AddElementConvention<RibbonButton>(
            RibbonButton.ContentProperty, "DataContext", "Click");
    }
}
```

This is not at any means all you should do in your bootstrapper. Just to show the right place.

Comment: Sorry I can't test it. I still didn't install .NET 4.5.